# How can I make a Bootstrap .nav-list hide and show distinct div elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just used a Bootstrap `.nav-tabs` which actually makes the tab function of showing/hidding content:

```
<div class="tabbable">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li><a href="#tab-perfiles" data-toggle="tab">Perfiles</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-mallas" data-toggle="tab">Mallas</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-laminas" data-toggle="tab">Láminas</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-corrugado" data-toggle="tab">Corrugado</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-cables" data-toggle="tab">Cables</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-tecnologico" data-toggle="tab">Tecnológico</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">

        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-perfiles">

        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-mallas">

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

So clicking at any tab will make the `div` inside `.tab-content` being displayed and hiding the rest.

But what about using a `.nav-list`?

For example, I got:

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
    <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#someDiv">Info</a></li>
    <li><a href="#anotherDiv">Applications</a></li>
    <li><a href="#thisOtherDiv">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#lastDiv">Team</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want it to be able to do the same, I tried using it within a `.tabbable` and adding a `.tab-content` below but got not results.

Actually I'd like the `.nav-list` and its *contents* to be inside a `.tab-content`:

```
<div class="tabbable">

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li><a href="#tab-perfiles" data-toggle="tab">Perfiles</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-mallas" data-toggle="tab">Mallas</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-laminas" data-toggle="tab">Láminas</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-corrugado" data-toggle="tab">Corrugado</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-cables" data-toggle="tab">Cables</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-tecnologico" data-toggle="tab">Tecnológico</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">

        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-perfiles">
            <div class="row tab-categoria-producto">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <ul class="nav nav-list">
                            <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#someDiv">Sasha</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#anotherDiv">Applications</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#thisOtherDiv">Profile</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#lastDiv">Akira</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <div id="sasha">Hola Sasha</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <div id="akira">Hola Akira</div>
                    </div>                            
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-mallas">

        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-laminas">

        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-corrugado">

        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-cables">

        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-tecnologico">

        </div>                
        <!-- Fin tab content   --> 
    </div>

</div> <!-- Fin tabbable   -->
```

I include this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hgL9B/2/)

Comment: In terms of the fiddle, you forgot to include jQuery which Bootstrap requires. http://jsfiddle.net/hgL9B/1/

Comment: You did not include jQuery or Javascript as any tags in your question. A solution is impossible without them.

Comment: Dome @fizzix Even I know it's all JavaScript which makes it possible I don't want to implement any JavaScript myself

Comment: I'm sorry, but that made no sense at all...

Comment: Just like in the nav-tabs, I'm not coding any JavaScript but using the Bootstrap JavaScript posibilities

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible without your own JS.  You just need the correct structure and class names.

Here's your corrected markup:

```
<!-- Top Tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab-perfiles" data-toggle="tab">Perfiles</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-mallas" data-toggle="tab">Mallas</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-laminas" data-toggle="tab">Láminas</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-corrugado" data-toggle="tab">Corrugado</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-cables" data-toggle="tab">Cables</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-tecnologico" data-toggle="tab">Tecnológico</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-perfiles">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row tab-categoria-producto">
                <!-- Tab 1 navigation -->
                <ul class="col-sm-3 nav nav-list">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#sasha" data-toggle="tab">Sasha</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#akira" data-toggle="tab">Akira</a></li>
                </ul>
                <!-- Tab 1 content -->
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <!-- Tab panes -->
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="sasha">Hola Sasha</div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="akira">Hola Akira</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-mallas">Content 2</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-laminas">Content 3</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-corrugado">Content 4</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-cables">Content 5</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-tecnologico">Content 6</div>
    <!-- Fin tab content -->
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/5BU2K/2/)**

Here's another demo of this that's less busy (it has less tabs and is cleaner as it only uses the necessary classes, rather than the OP's additional ones), in case others want to see it).

**[Nice clean demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/5BU2K/)**

Comment: You simply rocked it, THANKS. I have two main questions:

1st: When can I use the grid system classes in non `div` elements and when right at `div`s?

2nd: What does `.content-fluid` exactly do?

Comment: Glad to help.  1) The grid system classes can be used on pretty much any element you want.  They are floated so they become block level immediately.  In this scenario I used it on the <ul> because I wanted the padding to be part of that element, not part of a parent. 2) I think you mean `.container-fluid` and that is just a class to use when using Bootstrap rows to stop a horizontal scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at following example, a simple effort from my side. I hope it may work for you:

```
 <div id="rootwizard">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">First</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Second</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Third</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">Forth</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab5" data-toggle="tab">Fifth</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab6" data-toggle="tab">Sixth</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab7" data-toggle="tab">Seventh</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1">
          1
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
          2
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
            3
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
            4
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab5">
            5
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab6">
            6
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab7">
            7
        </div>
```